# Downloading multiple CSV files from a website with login and multiple pages

Tags: python, csv

Goal: I want to download daily data for every day going back several years off a website.
This website has a login and on each page it only has 7 CSV files, then you have to click previous one etc to view the previous 7. Ideally I wanna download all of these into one folder for all the daily data.
The link to the donwloading of the files does follow a very simple format which I attempted to take advantage of:

https://cranedata.com/publications/download/mfi-daily-data/issue/2020-09-08/

with the ending only changing for each date disregarding weekends.
I have attempted to modify several versions of code but ultimatly have not found anything that works.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ipython
# --------------------
import requests
import shutil
import datetime
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
dates=[datetime.datetime(2019,1,1)+datetime.timedelta(dval) for dval in range(0,366)];
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
for dateval in dates:
    r = requests.get('https://cranedata.com/publications/download/mfi-daily-data/issue/'+dateval.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), stream=True)
    if r.status_code == 200:
        with open(dateval.strftime('%Y%m%d')+".csv", 'wb') as f:
            r.raw.decode_content = True
            shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, f)
    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This does seem to work for other files on other websites but the CSV files do not actually have data when I download them.

This is what my excel files say instead of the actual data:
https://prnt.sc/ugju49

Answer (score 0):

You need to add authentication information to the request. This is either done using a "header", or in via a "cookie". You can use a [requests.Session](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects) object to simplify this for both.

To be able to give you more details is not possible without knowing which technologies are used for authentication.

Chances are (by the looks of the site) that it uses a server-side session. So there should be something like a "session id" or "sid" in your headers when "talking to the back-end". You need to open the browser's "developer tools" and look closely at the "request headers". Also the response and response-headers when you perform a login.

If you are very lucky, just using a `requests.Session` might be enough as long as you perform a login in the beginning of the session. Something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ipython

import requests
import shutil
import datetime

dates=[datetime.datetime(2019,1,1)+datetime.timedelta(dval) for dval in range(0,366)];

with requests.Session() as sess:
    sess.post(authentication-details)
    for dateval in dates:
        r = sess.get('https://cranedata.com/publications/download/mfi-daily-data/issue/'+dateval.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), stream=True)
        if r.status_code == 200:
            with open(dateval.strftime('%Y%m%d')+".csv", 'wb') as f:
                r.raw.decode_content = True
                shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, f)
```

If this does not work you need to closely inspect the network-tab in the developer tools and pick out the interesting bits and reproduce them in your code.

Which parts are the "interesting bits" depends on the back-end, and without further details, I cannot say.

Comment: Thank you. So I followed the steps and I managed to find a sessionid under "cookie" in the headers. I tried following the link you gave but I am honestly a bit lost as to how to implement this session id or cookie into my code? Or could it be that this is not the correct sessionid I am working with? @exhuma

Comment: It is really hard to say. There are many ways for doing authentication on the web. And the chance of finding two sites that do it in the same way are small. Without having a login/password to the site to investigate this ourselves it is impossible to say for certain.

Comment: Ok so I seem to be getting 200 as my output now meaning it does connect, and 
print(r.status_code == requests.codes.ok) comes back as true.

However I am still seeing the same thing in the excel. Could it be that this method is just not downloading the CSV file correctly and that I have had the connection to the server all along? If so do you have any suggestions to fix this? @exhuma

Comment: Again, without having more details it is hard to respond. Have you tried just dumping the contents of `response.content` into a file (opened in binary mode)?